# Is a join with a temporary table having fewer columns than original table faster than join with original table?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

Keeping in mind that Redshift is a columnar database server,Lets say I have a table A with 50 columns and I need to join it with table B but I need only 10 columns from table A in my final join result.
Lets say table C is a temp table created from Table A with the 10 columns I need.

1. Will [ Table C join Table B] be faster than [Table A join Table B]
2. Assuming Table A was a temporary table itself (derived from other tables), will your response to #1 still hold ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift does have other optimizations beyond just storing columns separately.

That said, I would expect very similar performance between referencing all 10 columns in a single table versus referencing 10 columns from a table with more columns.  It is hard to think of optimizations that would would be affected by unreferenced columns.

I don't understand the second part of the question.  A table is a table, whether temporary or not.  If you mean "Is there a performance difference between a temporary table and running a subquery/CTE?".  Then yes, there is definitely a difference.  For instance, there is overhead in creating a table, storing the data, and re-reading it.  On the other hand, the optimizer might choose a better execution plan for the temporary table -- that is not typical, but it happens.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, super helpful !
Btw, second part of my question just meant - would it make a difference if table A is temporary vs not temporary, but you have answered it already.